# Disconnect / disallow own application to users facebook (SDK PHP API)

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

I am working on a small facebook application (PHP 3.x SDK), but now I need some help.. :(

I was wondering if it is possible to disallow your own application for the facebook user, let's say:

**there is a button:**

Connect your facebook to "my-cool-application"

**and if the user doesn't want to anymore, they can**

disconnect your facebook from "my-cool-application"

Is there somebody that knows more about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically do this right now: there is no way to remove your own application permissions. The user will have to go remove your application through the **Privacy Settings** options.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information! This changes a lot in the functionality of my application, to bad :(