# Programmatically disconnecting Facebook account

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I have a button to connect to my application and would like to provide option to programmatically disconnect my Facebook account from the application. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted without any feedback, but I'd be curious to hear if this is possible.

Comment: It sees this question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656912/disconnect-disallow-own-application-to-users-facebook-sdk-php-api

Answer (score 0):

It would be a nice feature, but afaik it is not possible. Would be interesting to make a feature request to facebook though.